# Bulk Edit Media Library alt, caption, image names

Tags: plugins, database, media-library, import, export

I need to bulk edit images names, alt and captions of about 300+ images. My edit is to remove underscores that were auto generated to replace spaces and use them as alt. A CSV will help a lot but I couldn't find a plugin for that. It seems like there isn't any plugin catered to import/export Media Library as CSV. Is there a technical reason for this or it just doesn't have a market for such request?

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in bulk using WPallimport plugin: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/images/meta-data/